# If Spock is half-Human, why is his anatomy entirely Vulcan?

Tags: star-trek, spock

Sarek and Amanda's son Spock is half Vulcan half human but he looks no different from other Vulcans. On the episode Naked Time, Bones was giving him a checkup and the way he explains Spock's anatomy it is full Vulcan. If he is half human why does he have all Vulcan anatomy and no human features?

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe - the other question only touches on a couple of matters of appearance, while the dialogue from The Naked Time that prompted this question is about stark distinctions in basic physiological functions.

Comment: My understanding is his physiology is mostly Vulcan, but his mind is at least partially human (emotions, etc) that he tries to keep suppressed.

Comment: Could it be that Vulcan genes are generally *dominant* over the equivalent Human ones? Maybe he has one "pointed ear" gene and one "rounded ear" and the pointed ear gene is dominant.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - that's the explanation that was in one of the Star Trek EU books, but I've got 70+ of those and can't remember which one it was in.

Comment: Given that humans and vulcans are different species its likely some medical assistance was needed in spocks conception, it was probably easier to just make the baby predominately one species with added genes from the other rather that essentially create a whole new genetic system.